# Can we programmatically know wifi status in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can we obtain programmatically:

1. wifi enable time
2. wifi disable time
3. download file details
4. upload file details

Same as:

1. bluetooth enable time
2. disable time
3. file transfer details

Comment: What do you mean by 'download/upload file details through programmatically'?

Comment: Voted to close because, although you're asking how this can be done programatically, you don't mention which language you are trying to use.

Comment: @John Dibling: I don't think language is relevant here as a platform has been specified (Windows Phone) with a well-defined, language independent API.

Answer (score 4):

In short, no.

The only information currently available is the type (and sub-type) of the connection(s), whether it is enabled, whether roaming is on and which mobile operator is currently being used.

You can use the following to get a NetworkInterfaceInfo object (this gives you the type/sub-type, status etc. of the connection):

```
DeviceNetworkInformation.ResolveHostNameAsync(
            new DnsEndPoint("microsoft.com", 80),
            new NameResolutionCallback(nrr =>
            {
                NetworkInterfaceInfo info = nrr.NetworkInterface;
                if (info != null)
                {
                    switch (info.InterfaceType)
                    {
                        case NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet:
                            // USB connected
                            break;
                        case NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma:
                        case NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm:
                            switch (info.InterfaceSubtype)
                            {
                                case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_3G:
                                case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_EVDO:
                                case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_EVDV:
                                case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_HSPA:
                                    // 3g
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211:
                            // WIFI
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }), null);
```

Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202867%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) for more information.